# How to write to new line of a file with current code?

Tags: java, io

I have got this code to write to a file:

```
File cash = new File("cash/" + username + ".txt");
    if (!cash.exists()){
        try {
            cash.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {

        // Read File Contents - score
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cash/" + username + ".txt"));
        String storedScore="0";
        int storedScoreNumber = 0;
        while ((storedScore = br.readLine()) != null) {
            storedScoreNumber=(Integer.parseInt(storedScore==null ? "0" : storedScore));
            System.out.println("BeforeNum: " + storedScoreNumber);
        }

        // Write File Contents - incremented socre
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("cash/" + username + ".txt", false));
        out.write(String.valueOf(storedScoreNumber + (50)));
        //out.write(String.valueOf( Something on a new line ));
        System.out.println("AfterNum: " + String.valueOf(storedScoreNumber + (50)));
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

How at `out.write(String.valueOf( Something on a new line ));` can I write that text on a new line, instead of on the existing line?

I have tried putting \n in the string, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New lines vary depending on your operating system.

You can do this in several ways, the simplist for your current code is to use b.newLine().  b.newLine() will select the correct characters to use for your current platform and write it to the output.

Another option is to get the characters to use from System.getProperty("line.separator"), that will return the characters that represent a new line as a string.

I recommend the first approach.

Approach 1:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("cash/" + username + ".txt", false));
out.newLine();
out.write(String.valueOf(storedScoreNumber + (50)));
```

Approach 2:

```
    out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator")+String.valueOf(storedScoreNumber + (50)));
```